# Chef Automation issue | Vagrant: Bento/Centos-7 <- VirutalBox | Local: 2013 Macbook Pro MacOS

Tags: yaml, chef-infra

Running this off a 2013 MacBook Pro...

- Install Chef_workstation
- Install Vagrant
- mkdir chef_class
- mkdir cookbooks
- cd /chef_class/cookbooks
- vagrant box add bento/centos-7 --provider=virtualbox
- vagrant init bento/centos-7
- vagrant up
- git clone https://github.com/learn-chef/learn_chef_httpd.git
- cd /learn-chef/learn_chef_httpd
- So you should be in this file dir "/chef_class/cookbooks/learn_chef_httpd
- Everything will be there from being clones just have to edit your .kitchen.yml file
- run a "kitchen list"
- W ill show you all of your Vm's under suites:
- Run a kitchen create and then BAM
- but nah!.... doesn't work because its ass water

Error is a tty issue.

Kitchen.yaml:

```
# William Austin Daniel - 001074750
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# D085 - Automation & Scaling Script
# Written by: William Austin Daniel - 001074750
#             BS Cloud Computing 
# Date written: November 22nd, 2021 
# Description:
#   ---  The following script will be used to automatically horizontally scale up  
#        & down instances that Staellite Ads Inc will require for advertsing around the world. 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# START

driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:
    - ["public_network"] 
  customize:
    memory: 512 

provisioner:
    name: chef_zero
    product_name: chef
    product_version: 14.12.9

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7

suites:
 #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Satellite Terminal Server 
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Satellite-Terminal-Server.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Master Time Srvr
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Master-Time-srvr.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Database_Express-Server
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Database-Express-srvr.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Scaled Satellite Terminal Server
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Scaled-SAT-Terminal-srvr.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Scaled Web Server 
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Web-SAT-srvr.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Scale Time Server
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Time-SAT-Terminal-srvr.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - name: Core-Scaled Database Server
    driver:
      vm_hostname: Core-Database-SAT-Terminal-srvr.net
    run_list:
      - recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]
    attributes:
  
#END
```

Comment: Answer: You have to lay out the network parameters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.